# When alter table in mysql, change the index name, causes 1064 error

Tags: sql, mariadb

When I run the below query in Navicat,

```sql
ALTER TABLE `greenball`.`finals` 
RENAME INDEX `alias_UNIQUE` TO `finals_alias_unique`;
```

this query causes an error below:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB 
server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX`alias_UNIQUE` TO `finals_alias_unique` at line 2
```

[image]

I need your help !!!

Comment: Which MariaDB version are you using? (Seems like you need 10.5, or newer.)

Comment: 'From MariaDB 10.5.2, it is possible to rename an index using the RENAME INDEX' https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#rename-indexkey select version() to see what you are on.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)